# Is it a good idea to install gedit in Lubuntu?  

Tags: gedit, lubuntu, lxde

I've been a Ubuntu user for years now, but since 11.10 will come with GNOME3/Unity, neither of which I like, I've decided to switch to Lubuntu, which uses LXDE as the desktop environment.

The only problem I've come up with so far is that the default text editor, leafpad, doesn't support syntax highlighting. So far I've been using gedit for coding (html/php), I've customized it pretty nicely to work for what I need. Leafpad, however, is not customizable at all.

Thus, I ask:

> Is it a good idea to install gedit in Lubuntu?

I know it works, because I tried and all was simple, but since gedit is a GNOME app, I'm not certainly sure whether by using it I'm not breaking the overall system performance (by adding the "GNOME" part into the system).

**EDIT**

> What packages are listed when you try to install it in lubuntu? Can you share the list?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install gedit
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gedit-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 libgtksourceview-3.0-0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-common libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common zenity
  zenity-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gedit gedit-common gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0
  libgtksourceview-3.0-0 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libpeas-1.0-0
  libpeas-common zenity zenity-common
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 367 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,425 kB of archives.
After this operation, 11.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Comment: What packages are listed when you try to install it in lubuntu? Can you share the list? It will install the necessary libraries, the rest of the dependencies that are not satisfied, etc but will probably only call them when you run gedit and will go away when you close it. I dont think you will have anything loading if your not using the program so no performance issues.

Comment: There are two great alternative: scite and medit. No gtk3 deps, no gnome deps.
Great gtk editor with syntax h. and more.
try it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

None of the packages on that list will load anything that can make your system slow down.

It will install the necessary libraries, the rest of the dependencies that are not satisfied, etc but will only call them when you run gedit and will go away when you close it. I dont think you will have any performance issues related to installing gedit on your Lunbuntu system.

Comment: it's just that gedit is a more powerful and therefore starts a little slower on older computers than say leafpad and mousepad. but that's all

Answer (score 6):

[image]

gedit installs GTK+ libraries - GTK+ is already in use in parts of Lubuntu.

For example - the default editor `leafpad` is a GTK+ application.

No real Gnome dependencies are actually installed that you really dont want in LXDE such as gnome-panel.  Thus - dont expect any adverse "performance" issues when using gedit.